# Proving the convergence/divergence of a seemingly oscillating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How does one figure out whether this series: 
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{\ln\ln n}$$
converges or diverges? And, what is the general approach behind solving for convergence/divergence in a series that seems to "oscillate" (thanks to the -1 in this case)?

I have so far tried to split the function into two limits, but I am more or less stuck there.

Comment: Leibniz Criterion

Comment: aka Alternating series test :)

Comment: @user3776574 - Please remember to accept an answer. This will help users that might have a similar question in the future to more easily find the answer on the site. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n = \frac{1}{\ln{(\ln{(n)})}}$

Since $\ln(n)$ is increasing, we know $\ln{(\ln{(n)})}$ also increases, thus we have that:

$b_n = \frac{1}{\ln{(\ln{(n)})}}$ is monotonically decreasing on $[2,\infty)$ and also
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln{(\ln{(n)})}} = 0.$$
Thus, from Leibniz's Test for Alternating Series, we know
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\ln{(\ln{(n)})}}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{lnln(n)} 
$$

$$
for\ n>3, a_n>0
$$
Next you must show that this function is decreasing everywhere, and also that as n approaches infinity, a_n converges to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can apply [Leibniz alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)